# Best Mongoose schema when keys are dynamic

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Am trying to represent a library like this in Mongoose:

```
{
 'Book category 1': [ { title: 'Title 1', price: 33 }, ...],
 'Book category 2': [ { title: 'Title 2', price: 22 }, ...],
  ...
}
```

So

```
{ String: [{ title: String, price: Number}], ... }
```

The requirement is that I have to retrieve these arrays by key for sorting purposes (sorting/grouping by key (categories) and in the nested objects)

From what I've been reading I can either use Mixed type (which am not a fan of because I have well defined objects in the arrays for each key) - or a Map.

Is something like this the best way to go about it?

```
library: {
    type: Map,
    of: [{
      title: String,
      price: Number,
    }]
  }
```

(unsure if this would work)

Edit:
Should also add that I need each object in the array to have an id, so maybe something like this is more appropriate?

```
const Book = new Schema({
  title: String,
  price: Number,
});

const Library = new Schema({
  libraryMap: { type: Map, of: [Book] },
});
```

Comment: off topic, but wouldn't a `{ title: 'Book title', source: [ { seller: 'Name', price: 33} ] }` kind of object be more suitable?

Comment: I've edited my question due to a mistake in my formatting. I would like to sort by my key which is a category.

Comment: so what is this `library`? can u just your schema?